# What is the big-O of an embedded loop that removes elements in each iteration?

Tags: algorithm, loops, big-o, computer-science

If I had a while loop inside a while loop, and the inner while loop removes objects from a collection in its iteration, what is the running time?

Code:

```
while(!list.isEmpty()) {
    Iterator i = list.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()) {
        // do something
        if(meets some requirement)
            i.remove();
    }
}
```

list is guaranteed to be empty eventually, but how many times it loops depends on the contents.

What would be the time complexity of this?

Comment: Depends on "meets some requirement" condition.

Comment: You have to be very careful which quantity you establish as the "counting unit". You are asking for "how many times it loops", but another (equally valid) question is how often the "meets some requirements" has to be evaluated, which could, of course, be quite costly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really is going to depend on the condition when the element is removed.

Examine the following 3 scenarios:

1. meets some req. == true

   The element is always removed, and thus the outer loop actually is doing a single iteration, since after the first iteration, the list is empty. In this case, complexity is `O(n)`
2. meets some req. == false

   The element is never removed. This yields in endless iterations of the outer loop, since the list is never going to be empty, resulting in `O(infinity)` time complexity.
3. meets some requirement is true only on first iteration of inner loop.

   Here, for each iteration of outer loop, the list is getting shortened by one element. This means the outer loop will need to run `n` times, and the complexity will be `O(n+n-1+...+2+1)=O(n^2)`

As you can see, the time required is heavily dependent on the exact condition, and it can range anywhere from `O(n)` to `O(infinity)`

---

**EDIT** (as response to comments):

You state that at each iteration at least one element is removed. In this case, the complexity is somewhere between `Theta(n)` to `Theta(n^2)`, so you can say it is in `O(n^2)` - though with more details you might get tighter bound.

It depends if the list gets shrinked in a constant number or in a something that depends on the size. For example, if in each iteration half of the current elements are removed, you get time complexity of `O(n+n/2+n/4+...+1) = O(n)`.

Comment: The list is guaranteed to become empty, so is there a general case? Sometimes the loop will remove 1, sometimes it will remove more than 1, but eventually every element will be removed.

Comment: @PLin If in each iteration at least one element is removed, the complexity is somewhere between `O(n)` to `O(n^2)` (so you can say it is `O(n^2)`, but it might not be a tight bound).